# Controllar scroll para que ande em sections do site

Tags: jquery, html, aplicação-web

Tenho um site com sections .. estou tentando fazer com que o scroll fique pulando para a próxima section e assim por diante.. Agradeço desde de já!

Comment: está tentando como? cola o código pra gente ver

Comment: Na verdade não sei como fazer isto ... quero fazer parecido com este site:

Comment: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/skins/star-guardian-2016

Comment: tem varios jeitos de implementar isso. Tenta isso aqui: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoMoraleida :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitos plugins que fazem isso para você, recomendo o uso do [fullPage.js](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).
Para utilizar, basta usar o seguinte código:

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

No seu javascript basta usar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

Comment: Obrigadoo feraaa